# find snapshots whose volumes are deleted

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to find out how many snapshots are there whose volumes are deleted. In this scenario there is a volume **v-fffff** whose snapshot is available but volume is deleted. I dont know how can I find it. Below is the code

```
volList=[{"VolumeId":"vol-sss","State":"in-use"},{"VolumeId":"vol-defghi","State":"available"},{"VolumeId":"vol-sfjfrf","State":"in-use"}]
snapList=[{"VolumeId":"vol-sss","snap-id":"sna-1356"},{"VolumeId":"vol-sss","snap-id":"sna-asd"},{"VolumeId":"vol-defghi","snap-id":"snap-1256"},{"VolumeId":"vol-defghi","snap-id":"snap-11"},{"VolumeId":"vol-sfjfrf","snap-id":"snap-456"},{"VolumeId":"v-fffff","snap-id":"snap-123"}]

for snap in snapList:
    for vol in volList:
        if snap['VolumeId'] == vol['VolumeId']:
            print "match volume id :"  + snap['VolumeId'] + " state " + vol['State'] + " snap-id : " + snap['snap-id']  
        else:
            print "not match volume id :"  + snap['VolumeId'] + " state not found"  + " snap-id : " + snap['snap-id']
```

Comment: You show the code, but what is your question  ?

Comment: my question is volumeid v-fffff is present in snaplist but it not available in vollist and I want to extract that volumeid from the list

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution. Indexing was the solution for such scenario**

```
volList=[{"VolumeId":"vol-sss","State":"in-use"},{"VolumeId":"vol-defghi","State":"available"},{"VolumeId":"vol-sfjfrf","State":"in-use"}]
snapList=[{"VolumeId":"vol-sss","snap-id":"sna-1356"},{"VolumeId":"vol-sss","snap-id":"sna-asd"},{"VolumeId":"vol-defghi","snap-id":"snap-1256"},{"VolumeId":"vol-defghi","snap-id":"snap-11"},{"VolumeId":"vol-sfjfrf","snap-id":"snap-456"},{"VolumeId":"v-fffff","snap-id":"snap-123"}]
print len(snapList)
volIdList=[]
for ids in volList:
    volIdList.append(ids['VolumeId'])
mainSnap=[]
for snap in snapList:
    try:
        if (volIdList.index(snap['VolumeId'])< 0):
            print " not match volume id :"  + snap['VolumeId']  
        else:
            for v in volList:
                if v['VolumeId']==snap['VolumeId']:
                    print "match volume id :"  + snap['VolumeId'] + " " + v['State'] + " " + snap['snap-id']   

    except ValueError:
        print " state not found " + snap['VolumeId'] + " " + snap['snap-id']
```